# Advanced Custom activation function in keras + tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, activation-function

```
def newactivation(x):
    if x>0:
        return K.relu(x, alpha=0, max_value=None)
    else :
        return x * K.sigmoid(0.7* x)

get_custom_objects().update({'newactivation': Activation(newactivation)})
```

I am trying to use this activation function for my model in keras, but I am having hard time by finding what to replace

```
if x>0:
```

ERROR i got:

> File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 614, in **bool**
>       raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
>
> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if >t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and >use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on >the value of a tensor.

Can someone make it clear for me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if x > 0` doesn't make sense because `x > 0` is a tensor, and not a boolean value.

To do a conditional statement in Keras use `keras.backend.switch`.

For example your

```
if x > 0:
   return t1
else:
   return t2
```

Would become

```
keras.backend.switch(x > 0, t1, t2)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
def newactivation(x):
    return tf.cond(x>0, x, x * tf.sigmoid(0.7* x))
```

x isn't a python variable, it's a Tensor that will hold a value when the model is run. The value of x is only known when that op is evaluated, so the condition needs to be evaluated by TensorFlow (or Keras).

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the tensor and then check for the condition

```
from keras.backend.tensorflow_backend import get_session


sess=get_session()
if sess.run(x)>0:
    return t1
else:
    return t2
```

get_session is not available for TensorFlow 2.0. Solution for that you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58255821/how-to-use-k-get-session-in-tensorflow-2-0-or-how-to-migrate-it)

Answer (score 0):

inspired by the previous answer from ed Mar 21 '18 at 17:28
tomhosking. This worked for me. [tf.cond](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond)

```
def custom_activation(x):
    return tf.cond(tf.greater(x, 0), lambda: ..., lambda: ....)
```