# How to use K.get_session in Tensorflow 2.0 or how to migrate it?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, real-time, tensorflow2.0

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__.update(self._defaults) # set up default values
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs) # and update with user overrides
    self.class_names = self._get_class()
    self.anchors = self._get_anchors()
    self.sess = K.get_session()
```

RuntimeError: `get_session` is not available when using TensorFlow 2.0.

Answer (score 33):

Tensorflow 2.0 does not expose the backend.get_session directly any more but the code still there and expose for tf1.

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L465

You can use it with tf1 compatible interface:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.get_session()
```

Or import tenforflow backend with internal path:

```
import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K
sess = K.get_session()
```

Answer (score 5):

In order to avoid using `get_session` after tensorflow 2.0 upgrade, Use `tf.distribute.Strategy` to get model. To load model, use `tf.keras.models.load_model`

```
import tensorflow as tf

another_strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with another_strategy.scope():
    model = Service.load_deep_model()

def load_deep_model(self, model):
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("model.h5")
    return loaded_model
```

Hope this helps. As this worked for me.

I have tried to explain same at this utility article as well. https://www.javacodemonk.com/runtimeerror-get_session-is-not-available-when-using-tensorflow-2-0-f7238546

Answer (score 0):

Probably has something to do with tf 2.0 eager execution that is enabled by default.
Try 
import tensorflow as tf

tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

Comment: I have disabled eager execution, and I still have the get_session problem, so it is not related.

Comment: I don't think this is related.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and tried installing and uninstalling. In the end, I found that the library was not actually installed correctly.

I went through each library in my:

```
C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\
```

I tracked down the file in within the site-packages in Keras, which was calling from the Tensorflow library, which was calling from another folder. I found the final folder had the get_session(), but this was not being called in. When I checked the directory, I found that get_session wasn't being loaded in. Within the file directory /tensorflow/keras/backend.py it was importing everything, but missed out the get_session.

To fix this I added this line:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.backend import get_session
```

Then saved it. The next time I ran my code it was fine.

I gave the same answer for this page [How to fix ' module 'keras.backend.tensorflow_backend' has no attribute '_is_tf_1''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58047454/how-to-fix-module-keras-backend-tensorflow-backend-has-no-attribute-is-tf/65484222#65484222)